# Camel FTP endpoint move to a folder based on date

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel route consuming from an FTP server and storing any files it consumes to a directory with move=.dealtWith. However, the number of files in this .dealtWith directory can quickly become unmanageable for users to view, so I would like to move the file to a .dealtWith/{the_date} directory. Is there a way to specify this functionality in camel without bringing the route down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Camel Simple Expression Language

```
ftp:url?move=.dealtWith/${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd}/${header.CamelFileName}
```